# Typescript function argument type check without interface

Tags: typescript

How can I force typescript to check for correct function argument count and number without using interface method?

I do not want to use intreface, since I would have to create interface for each possible function types combinations.

Following code does not throw error when compiling with tsc (without parameters)

```
let aaa: (x: number, y: number) => string = function(arg: number): string { return 'a'; };
```

Following code also does not throw an error:

```
let aaas: (x: number, y: number) => string = function(): string { return 'a'; };
```

my tsc version is

```
Version 2.9.2
```

My idea is to use this normally when I have function as argument (when using callbacks for sql or another work done in code). 
I would not like to create interface every single time I want to add callback. My goal is to make this work for user defined classes

example:

```
export class LinkedList<V> {


 public serialize(serializeValue: (val: V) => void) {
    //todo
    serializeValue(some...)
  }
```

The linkedList can, obviously, have inside a class instance or so.
Is there a way to force tsc throw compile error if I make mistake and provide invalid function as callback?

Thank you

Comment: Read through [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters) and review whether you want to consider the function invalid.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I will have to be careful about that what I write as code then...